# CURL and ZLIB Compilation

Tags: c++, curl, zlib

When compiled correctly, how are these two associated together? I'm attempting to use the ZLIB library in my CURL install and want to confirm that I've compiled CURL and ZLIB correctly. Should the libcurl.lib now have all of ZLIB after a successful compile or is the zlib.lib library still required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .lib archives are just a collection of compiled source files, nothing more. By convention and practicality, they only include the objects compiled for their respective library. So, to link against the libcurl you have created, you must also link against the zlib. Professional configuration systems (e.g. pkg-config) will automate this step away from you, but you'll always need the zlib.lib if you didn't do any linker magic.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not like that. When you compiled CURL with ZLIB SUPPORT, those header files were included in CURL source which were needed for compiling the function/API's present in the ZLIB  library.

You would never be able to compile CURL with ZLIB support with ZLIB library in your sustem.

Consider, CURL with ZLIB is just a program which you would write to call functions provided by 
ZLIB.